# trigger CheckedChanged programmatically for toggleButton (CompoundButton)

Tags: android, android-view

How can I trigger programmatically the following method : (without clicking/swiping the on/off toggle switch)

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
{
  //randomness
}
```

I figured an alternative way would be, calling

```
switch1.setChecked(true);
```

Then doing a manual check.

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do this, what do you want to achieve? Nevertheless you can get `isChecked` direct from the `CompoundButton` like this `switch1.isChecked()` and then do what you like with it. Or as you say just call `switch1.setChecked(!switch1.isChecked)` to trigger the event

Answer (score 3):

There actually is a way of calling it if you refer to the class methods ;)

`ToggleButton t = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.myToggle); t.performClick();`

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#performClick()

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of calling the `onCheckedChanged` of a CompoundButton (ToggleButton or Switch) like this.

However, I see two other solutions:

1. Keep the listener object around and manually calling the `onCheckedChanged` function with the button and the boolean.
2. Abstract the logic inside the `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangedListener` implementation into another function that you can call manually.